# Setting maxfps using Config in Python's Kivy doesn't limit the fps

Tags: python, kivy, frame-rate

I want to define a limit for fps in Kivy.

I tried to limit fps to 60 with `Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '60')` but I was still getting around 70 to 80 fps at least according to `Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: print(Clock.get_fps()), 1)`.

Here's my full code:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '60')


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: print(Clock.get_fps()), 1)
        return Label(text='Hello world!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Does setting a lower value do anything?

Comment: @inclement Nope, I tried setting it to 60, 30 and even to 1 FPS but no effect.

Comment: Has this issue been reported to the Kivy Devs?  It's a must fix if you plan on building apps for mobile and having good fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import order is important here. The example works when importing the config before importing anything else kivy related:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', '10')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label



class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: print(Clock.get_fps()), 1)
        return Label(text='Hello world!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

As mentioned in the related github issue on the Kivy bugtracker, FPS might over/undershoot slightly but it's a general direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put first `import config` then you need to put the config set, it should work like this.